# Powershell script doenst run scheduled task

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

I'm running a scheduled Task from my ASP MVC5 web app, using the following command 
`pipeline.Commands.AddScript("schtasks.exe /change /s server1 /ru system  /tn MyTask /sd 10/06/2015 /st 11:30 ");`

In the scheduled task manager in remote server (Server1) the start dateTime of MyTaskchanges to 10/06/2015 11:30 but the status of The task doesnt move to RUNING when it's 11:30 it's stays ready.

I neeed to know why please.

Comment: Is the date `10/06/2015` just a sample or is it what you are actually trying?

Comment: Might be a UI issue. Check the task history to see if it's being run.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin No it's just a sample

Comment: ok, can you give use the task initial details before being updated?

Comment: @vonPryz when i check history it's there but it does not execute wanted task

Comment: "History it's there" means A) that the task has been run according to the history or B) that the task has not been run. Which one you mean?